# SQL hashbytes update statement not as expected

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to update a column on SQL server r2 using the hashbytes command. Here's the simplified version of the command:

```
COMMAND: "UPDATE [tbl] SET [checksum] = HASHBYTES('MD5',[field1])"
```

The problem is that, it writes strange characters like this to all the fields:

`"˜Iý¸¶C"KéS©c"`

However, if I do a select (using the same fields):

```
select HASHBYTES('MD5',[field1]) from [tbl];
```

It returns a correct string:

```
0x9849FDB80C17B64322DA094BE963A963
```

Anyone know why it would do this. I've tried on a test database and the update command works as expected. But it doesn't work on our production server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you are getting this is because HASHBYTES returns a binary data type, and this is not text.

Using the build in function fn_varbintohexstr you can convert the binary data into text, as follows:

```
UPDATE [tbl] SET [checksum] = master.dbo.fn_varbintohexstr(HASHBYTES('MD5',[field1]))
```